# Undefined error in MEAN CRUD

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angularjs, crud

```
{ text: undefined,
  done: false,
  _id: 529e16025f5222dc36000002,
  __v: 0 }
PUT /api/todos/529e16025f5222dc36000002 200 142ms - 68b
```

I keep getting this error when trying to do an update for my simple CRUD todo list. When I submit the update, the change doesn't appear on screen, although the put says it's a 200. Not sure what steps to take so that I don't get this "undefined" error and so I can have the update show up on screen.

EDIT: Included more code

This is the back-end node code:

```
app.put('/api/todos/:_id', function(req, res) {
    Todo.findById(req.params._id, function(err, todos){
    todos.text = req.body.text;
    console.log(todos);
    todos.save(function() {
            if (!err) {
                res.send(todos);
            } else if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);
                res.json(todos);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This is the Angular front-end code:

```
$scope.updateTodo = function(id) {
    $scope.newItem = prompt("Please enter your new item:", "");
    $http.put('/api/todos/' + id, {formData: $scope.newItem}).success(function(data) {
        $scope.todos = data;
    });

    $http.get('/api/todos').success(function(data) {
        $scope.todos = data;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of this:

```
$http.put('/api/todos/' + id, { formData: $scope.newItem} )
                                ^^^^^^^^
```

You're passing a single `formData` parameter with the request, yet in your Express code, you use this:

```
req.body.text
```

Either try this:

```
req.body.formData.text
```

Or don't use the `formData` parameter at all and pass `$scope.newItem` directly.

Besides that, your Express code is a bit messy: it might send back multiple responses and it doesn't check for errors on the `save` (as @PaulGray also pointed out).